Unity 2D Platform Game AI
Im trying to make an ai enemy but when i build the game it says "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Dusman.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Dusman.cs:19)".
I didnt try anything because i cant and i dont know how to solve this please help me.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dusman : Skeleton
{
    private DusmanDurum mevcutDurum;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        DurumDegistir(new DusunmeDurum());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mevcutDurum.Execute();
    }

    public void DurumDegistir(DusmanDurum yeniDurum)
    {
        if (mevcutDurum != null)
        {
            mevcutDurum = yeniDurum;
            mevcutDurum.Enter(this);
        }
    }

    public void Hareket()
    {
        MyAnimator.SetFloat("karakterHizi", 1);
        transform.Translate(YonAyarla() * (hiz * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    public Vector2 YonAyarla()
    {
        return sagaBak ? Vector2.right : Vector2.left;
    }
}



using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class DevriyeDurum : DusmanDurum
{
    private Dusman dusman;
    private float devriyeZamanlayici;
    private float devriyeSuresi = 10;

   public void Enter(Dusman dusman)
    {
        this.dusman = dusman;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Debug.Log("Devriye atıyorum...");
        Devriye();
        dusman.Hareket();
    }

    public void Exit()
    {

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)
    {
       
    }

    private void Devriye()
    {
        devriyeZamanlayici += Time.deltaTime;

        if (devriyeZamanlayici >= devriyeSuresi)
        {
            dusman.DurumDegistir(new DusunmeDurum());
        }
    }
}



using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class DusunmeDurum : DusmanDurum
{
    private Dusman dusman;
    private float dusunmeZamanlayici;
    private float dusunmeSuresi = 5;

    public void Enter(Dusman dusman)
    {
        this.dusman = dusman;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Debug.Log("Şu an hiçbir şey yapmadan duruyorum");
        Dusunme();
    }

    public void Exit()
    {

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider2D other)
    {

    }

    private void Dusunme()
    {
        dusman.MyAnimator.SetFloat("karakterHizi", 0);
        dusunmeZamanlayici += Time.deltaTime;

        if(dusunmeZamanlayici >= dusunmeSuresi)
        {
            dusman.DurumDegistir(new DevriyeDurum());
        }
    }
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface DusmanDurum
{
    void Execute();
    void Enter(Dusman dusman);
    void Exit();
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider2D other);
}




using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Skeleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator MyAnimator { get; private set; }
    protected bool sagaBak;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject bicakPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    protected float hiz;
    


    public bool Atak { get; set; }

    public void YonDegistir()
    {
        sagaBak = !sagaBak;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x * -1, 1, 1);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public virtual void Start()
    {
        sagaBak = true;
        MyAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public virtual void BicakFirlat(int value)
    {     
        if (sagaBak)
        {
            GameObject klonBicak = (GameObject)Instantiate(bicakPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 90)));

            klonBicak.GetComponent<Bicak>().Initialize(Vector2.right);
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject klonBicak = (GameObject)Instantiate(bicakPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, -90)));

            klonBicak.GetComponent<Bicak>().Initialize(Vector2.left);
        }
    }
}


And these are my codes for my AI enemy.

1 you never set mevcutDurum to anything 2. you use OnTriggerEnter but claim its a 2d game so thats never going to run.. i gave up after that.. PS next time at least put the classes in their own code blocks

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
